# How about prioritized locations in export

Tags: export

When sending mass mailings the recipient's email address locations may be handled prioritized if authors want to: Use location x and if contact doesn't hold such an address use main address.

It would be great to provide such a decision for exports: Export address of location x but if it doesn't exist, use main address.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the address fields to export, if you specify the location "Primary" you'll get the address that's marked as the primary in the contact record. There's also an address location field you can export so you can tell which location was exported.

If you need something specific (use work if it exists, otherwise use home), I'd export both locations and use spreadsheet formulas to select one or the other.